# Join all faces in a mesh together at once

Tags: faces, cloth-simulation

I imported a model from somewhere and all of the faces on it are separated from each other. It's not noticeable when just using the armature, but I'm trying to do a cloth simulation for part of it so it all just falls apart. Is there a way to join everything together at the edges? If there is, how would I do it? Thanks!

Comment: If the vertices are coincident, that would be M  (merge) > By Distance, all selected.

Comment: Are the vertices of the neighboring faces at the same location? If that is the case you could try *Mesh > Clean up > Merge By Distance*.

Answer (score 0):

In *Edit Mode* select all, *Merge by Distance*, and keep increasing the merge distance from the default value until all the intersection points merge.